# Android permission check not recognized

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to access the `FusedLocationApi` in Android 23.

I've created a `PermissionUtils` class that has some methods to check if permissions are granted or not.

```
public class PermissionUtils {

    private static abstract class AbstractPermission {

        public static boolean check(Context context, String permission) {
            return (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        }

        /**
         * Requests the permission. If a rationale with an additional explanation should
         * be shown to the user, displays a dialog that triggers the request.
         */
        public static void request(Activity activity, int requestId, String permission) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {
                // TODO - Display a dialog with rationale.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, requestId);
            } else {
                // Location permission has not been granted yet, request it.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, requestId);
            }
        }
    }

    public static final class FineLocation {
        private static final String permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        private static final String permissionCellTowerPrecision = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
        private static final int requestId = PermissionCodes.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE;

        public static boolean check(Context context) {
            return AbstractPermission.check(context, permission) && AbstractPermission.check(context, permissionCellTowerPrecision);
        }

        public static void request(Activity activity) {
            AbstractPermission.request(activity, requestId, permission);
        }
    }
}
```

In a Fragment, I'm calling the `FineLocation.check()`.

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (PermissionUtils.FineLocation.check(getActivity())) {
            PermissionUtils.FineLocation.request(getActivity());
        } else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }
}
```

The problem is that I'm still getting the error: `Call requires permission which may be rejected by the user`.

How can I tell the Inspector that I've checked for the permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is that the Inspector does not recognize that I am checking for the permission.
The code is compiling fine and the app can be installed on the USB device or Emulator.

You can toggle the severity of the inspection by going to:

`Settings > Editor > Inspections > Android > Constant and Resource Type Mismatches`

The severity is by default `error`. You can set it as `warning`, so that it will still announce you, so that you'll be sure you're checking for the permission.